# How to get passed System.UnauthorizedAccessException when writing to a file in Application.StartUpPath?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I'm writing to a file I created in Application.StartUpPath in Visual Studios it gives me the System.UnauthorizedAccessException error. Is there a way to allow access to it? c:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs:line 112 is the direct path that the error is producing. I already tried File.SetAttributes. This is the area producing the error:

```
public void writeAll()
    {
        var path = Application.StartupPath;
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.CreateText(path);
            }

            using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(path))
            {                                       
                foreach (TextBox textBox in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    Writer.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
                }

                foreach (Label label in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                {
                    Writer.WriteLine(label.Text);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Why would you like to overwrite your executable file with text lines?

Comment: Saving data in a .txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application.StartupPath is just the folder that your application is run from. With your current code, you are trying to create a text file with just the folder. You need to specify a name for the text file. Try using Path.Combine() with Application.StartupPath and a string for the text file. So for example:

```
string fileName = "myFile.txt";
string fileLocation = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, fileName);
if(!File.Exists(fileLocation))
{ File.Create(fileLocation); }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Application.StartupPath` is a folder.

If you want to create a file in that folder, you need to use `Path.Combine()` to add a filename.

Comment: If I'm trying to make a .txt file inside it for saving data how would I check to see if it exists then create it if it isn't?

Comment: You'll also want to make sure you have write privileges in the location as well. I believe that would also cause an `UnauthorizedAccessException` (at least I'm sure it would if you had to create a subfolder there in the process)

Comment: How do I change those permissions?

Comment: Right click on location > properties > security

Comment: @JesseWells: If you're running in Program Files, you cannot change anything.  If you're running out of the debugger, you're fine.

Comment: Should I just give full control to everything?

Comment: @JesseWells: You should not change permissions.

Comment: So it made a textfile and populated it with strings, but its not reading when I launch the program again...

Comment: @JesseWells: That's probably because your code overwrites the file.